How to extract Android page text style information?
I want to extract text style information (such as bold, color, and other information) from android pages, because I found different styles for the same line of text in some android pages,
and I just want to extract the bolded information from it, how should I achieve this? The xml files I get from some tools don't contain text style information, can anyone help me?
